# Linux -- How to Install Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iso-image

I have Win 10 Enterprise Machine x64.

and I have Windows Server 2012 R2 Machine.

I am a very beginner to Linux OS/Administration.

Keeping in mind SQL Server on Linux I want to install Ubuntu Linux OS on above two machines.

Can anyone guide me on how to Install. Which ISO file should I use and how to run the ISO file.

[image]

But seriously I don't know how to install using this ISO file.

Regards, kindly understand my lack of knowledge.

Comment: The server ISO doesn't contain the GUI (graphical user interface).

Comment: You burn the ISO to a CD (or make a bootable USB) and boot the computer to your CD/USB and install from there.

Comment: Have you considered using [Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/) or [vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/), where Ubuntu may be considered a 'guest' OS running on a Windows 10 'host' ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `Microsoft SQL Server` you can't go with `Linux MS-SQL` which only runs on `Windows` or `Windows Server`. If you really want to use `Linux` then you need `mysql` or `postgresql`.

To get started with `Linux` specially with `Ubuntu Server` take a look at the Official Ubuntu Server Help Guide here https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide  and if you have any other questions then please use the http://askubuntu.com instead of this forum.